# Making it seems like the page is on sub domain, whereas it is in a nested MVC 3 site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, url-routing

I used to have a [BlogEngine.net](http://dotnetblogengine.net/) based blog, hosted in IIS7. Now I have added an ASP.NET MVC 3 site as a Virtual Application in the `/interesting/` folder in site's directory.

[image: IIS7 site nesting]

So my .net 2 blog is available at maxpavlov.com and mvc 3 app is `maxpavlov.com/interesting/`

I want to place a controller/view to my mvc3 site to allow file uploads. But I need the users to be able to reach it also via visiting `file.maxpavlov.com`

I know that I need to create a dns record for that sub domain to point to that very same server. Is it possible to configure IIS or MVC 3 routing or both to have the users that have arrived at `file.maxpavlov.com` to remain on that url, but to be actually fed the response as if they were visiting `maxpavlov.com/interesting/fileUpload/`?

Comment: caution with this as well having multiple folders with various versions. At some point you can run into a version inheritance issue that can be a pain to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without having some code/module process the mapping for you.
The problem is your host header will be file.maxpavlov.com and everything will still be treated as path based.

You could try to create your own rewrite, or simply use IIS's url rewriter.

See:
http://thethoughtfulcoder.com/blog/8/IIS-7-URL-Rewrite-subdomains-and-host-headers

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could create two seperate sites in IIS, then map the virtual directory to the same folder as the file. site, however you may run into problems with two different worker processes accessing the same folder (i'm not certain if this will be a problem or not).